# Android Aruco library usage

Tags: android, opencv, min3d, aruco

Evening,

I have been trying to use ARuco library to detect a marker. Downloaded all the Aruco libraries (aruco itself and min3d) and OpenCV 4 Android library. Set them up as libraries and imported them to ARuco sample code. All looks fine, no errors found here. The application starts fine, but if I start using any function that uses any of the listed libraries the application crashes.
In addition, if I incorporate Aruco and min3d libraries into an OpenCV4Android provided example and create a object of Aruco library class, the application does not start and the error message in LogCat is "Can`t create OpenGL context".

So, my question is: does anyone know how to properly setup the aruco-android libraries and start the samples provided? The aruco webpage "How to start", found on other question on stackoverflow, is down, and I cannnot find any info on the web. Also, is there anything wrong with the device I`m testing the application on (just because of the LogCat message and no errors in code)?

Comment: Did You crosscompile ArUco libraries yourself or did You just take the binaries for PC and try to use them on ARM architecture? Or are You using the java version?

Comment: I am using java version. The crash reason I found is that I create class object in a wrong place. Objects of classes should be made in onCameraViewStarted() method of activity.Do not know if there is still a reason to hold the question opened.

Comment: The best solution would be pasting the logcat log that gave You a hint, and posting an answer. This might help some poor soul in the future, if it faces Your problem :)